# Constructing a "Lebesgue-Stieltjes" measure in $\mathbb R^d$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

Given $x, y \in \mathbb R^d$, write $x \leq y$ iff $x_i \leq y_i$ for all $i$. We call a function $F : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ *monotone increasing* if $F(b) \geq F(a)$ whenever $b \geq a$ and *right-continuous* if $F(x_n) \to F(x)$ whenever $x_n \to x$ in $\mathbb R^d$ and $x_n \geq x_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Also, say that a monotone increasing, right-continuous function $F$ *vanishes at* $-\infty$ if
$$
F(-\infty) := \lim_{x_1 \to -\infty} \cdots \lim_{x_d \to -\infty} F(x) = 0.
$$
Also, we use the following notation:
$$
(a,b] := \prod_{i=1}^d (a_i, b_i] \quad \textrm{and} \quad (-\infty, b] := \prod_{i=1}^d (-\infty, b_i] \quad \textrm{for } a = (a_1, \ldots, a_d), \: b=(b_1, \ldots, b_d) \in \mathbb R^d.
$$
**My question:** Suppose $F : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ is monotone increasing, right-continuous, and vanishes at $-\infty$. Let $\mathcal A_0 = \left\{(-\infty, b] : b \in \mathbb R^d\right\}$, and define the set function $\mu : \mathcal A_0 \to [0,\infty)$ by $\mu((-\infty, b]) = F(b)$. Under what conditions does $\mu$ extend to a measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$?

The obvious answer would involve the measure extension theorem:

> Let $\mathcal A$ be a semiring and let $\mu : \mathcal A \to [0,\infty]$ be an additive, $\sigma$-subadditive and $\sigma$-finite set function with $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$. Then there is a unique $\sigma$-finite measure $\tilde\mu : \sigma(A) \to [0,\infty]$ such that $\tilde\mu(A) = \mu(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal A$.

The collection $\mathcal A_0$ isn't a semiring, but the collection $\mathcal A := \left\{(a,b] : a, b \in \mathbb R^d\right\}$ is. In dimension $d=1$, this is the idea behind Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures. In higher dimensions, it's easy to inductively extend $\mu$ to $\mathcal A$ so that $\mu : \mathcal A \to \mathbb R$ is additive. Obviously $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal A$, and $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$. But the remaining properties are giving me trouble.

In general, $\mu$ constructed from a monotone increasing, right-continuous $F$ need not even be positive. Take $F : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ so that $F(x,y) = 0$ if $x<0$ or $y<0$, and $F(x,y) = \arctan(x+y)$ otherwise. Then $F$ is right-continuous and monotone increasing, but if we let $\mu((-\infty, b]) = F(b_1, b_2)$, then the additive extension of $\mu$ to $\mathcal A \subset \mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)$ isn't positive:
\begin{align*}
\mu\big((0,1] \times (0,1]\big) &= \mu\big((0,1] \times (-\infty, 1]\big) - \mu\big((0,1] \times (-\infty, 0]\big) \\
&= \mu\big((-\infty, 1] \times (-\infty, 1]\big) - \mu\big((-\infty, 0] \times (-\infty, 1]\big) - \mu\big((-\infty, 1] \times (-\infty, 0]\big) + \mu\big((-\infty, 0] \times (-\infty, 0]\big) \\
&= \arctan(2) - 2\arctan(1) < 0.
\end{align*}

As for $\sigma$-additivity, I only know how to show this if $\mu((a,b])$ is monotone increasing in $b$ and monotone decreasing in $a$ (which is certainly true for Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures in dimension 1, where $\mu((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$). This is similarly difficult to show in higher dimensions.

**One possible direction:** Recently I came across the following result:

> Let $(F_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a uniformly bounded sequence of right-continuous, monotone increasing functions $F_n : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$. Then there is a right-continuous, monotone increasing, bounded function $F : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ and a subsequence $(F_{n_k})_{k \geq 1}$ for which $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} F_{n_k}(x) = F(x)$ for all $x$ where $F$ is continuous.

This theorem implies in particular that if $(\mu_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a family of sub-probability measures on $\mathbb R^d$, then the functions $F_n(x) = \mu_n((-\infty, x])$ admit a subsequence $(F_{n_k})$ and a monotone increasing, right-continuous bounded function $F$ for which $F_{n_k}(x) \to F(x)$ if $F$ is continuous at $x$. Since $\mu_n$ are measures and $F$ is monotone increasing, it follows that $F$ is nonnegative. And, if $(a,b] \subset \mathbb R^d$ is a half-open rectangle whose vertices are points of continuity for $F$, the inductive definition of $\mu$ on $\mathcal A$ implies that $\mu((a,b]) = \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} \mu_{n_k}((a,b]) \geq 0$. But showing that $\mu$ is positive in general on $A$ requires again showing that $\mu((a,b])$ is increasing in $b$ and decreasing in $a$, which I'm having trouble proving.

Does anyone know of such a construction of a measure in general on $\mathbb R^d$? What are peoples' thoughts?

Comment: In other words, when is a function of $d$ variables the CDF of a $\mathbb{R}^{d}$-valued random vector?  Or, how does one set up Riemann-Stieltjes integration in higher dimensions?  Shamefully, I had little luck finding answers through Google.  (Especially disappointed in Wikipedia here.)  I did come across *Essential Mathematics for Applied Fields* by Meyer, which covers these questions in Sections 10 and 11.  (The author proceeds by dealing with functions that are "monotone over boxes" and claims that this is stronger than "monotone in each coordinate.")

Comment: Ah, yes, Meyer does define the property of “$n$-*monotonicity*”, which is exactly the needed property. (This feels like an example of the research philosophy of “if the property you need is hard to prove, take it as an assumption” hahaha) Thank you for this reference!